# Invalid parameter number error when using whereIn with livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to create a multiple select filter. When I use whereIn for the id I get this error

> Invalid parameter number (SQL: select * from `stations` where `id` in (16128))

With 16128 being one of the two id's selected for that query. It works fine with a manual given array so I am not sure what the problem is. I also tried with array_values but I get the same result.

```
            <label for="" class="col-md-3">Daypart</label>
                <div class="container-checkbox">
                    @foreach($dayparts as $id => $daypart)
                        <div wire:key="{{ $daypart->id }}">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $daypart->daypart_name }}" name="{{ $daypart->daypart_name }}" wire:model="filters.dayparts.{{ $daypart->id }}" wire:click="filtru({{ $daypart->id }})" />
                        </div>
                    @endforeach                       
                </div>
```

```
 public function filtru($id){
        
        $this->filters['dayparts'] = array_filter($this->filters['dayparts']);
    
        $dayp =  DaypartStation::whereIn('daypart_id', array_keys($this->filters['dayparts']))->get();
        foreach($dayp as $day){
            $this->arr[]=$day->station_id;
        }
        
        $toate = Station::whereIn('id', [$this->arr])->get();
        //dd(Station::whereIn('id', $this->arr)->get());
        //dd(Station::whereIn('id', [array_values($this->arr)])->get());
        // dd(Station::whereIn('id', [16576, 16776, 16376])->get());
    }
 public function render()
    {
        
        return view('livewire.create-workbooks-table', [
            'stations'=> Station::
                when($this->filters['dayparts'], function($query){
                    $query->whereIn('id', [$this->arr]);
                    })
     
            
                    ->search($this->search)
                    ->orderBy($this->sortBy, $this->sortDirection)
                    ->latest()
                    ->Paginate($this->perPage), 
 
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: could you check what is the value of    ```$this->arr```  before the query is run ?

Comment: It returns the right array with the id's of the records. I have two dayparts that are connected with stations, one is evenings which is connected with one station and the other one is daytime which is connected with two stations. The "evening" one works somehow since it's only one id, but "daytime" gives this error. array:1 [▼
  0 => 15619
] and for daytime array:2 [▼
  0 => 16128
  1 => 16385
] so the data should be pulled

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change

```
 $toate = Station::whereIn('id', [$this->arr])->get();
```

to

```
 $toate = Station::whereIn('id', $this->arr)->get();
```

since `$this->arr` is already an array

Comment: it still doesn't change the outcome, I tried it either way